# Polygons not merging in QGIS when dissolving?

Tags: qgis, polygon, dissolve

I am new to QGIS and am trying to dissolve polygons in my shapefile using one of the fields in the attribute in QGIS 2.8.5. The process runs, and it does add a new map but nothing seems to have changed in the new map and the polygons chosen on the basis of the field are not merged.

If this is a known problem, how can I work around it?

Comment: My guess is this is there are either invalid geometries or topology errors. If you use the Topology Checker in QGIS to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Does it work if you try to dissolve all?

Comment: I tried geometry validity check and it threw no errors. I also tried changing projection to PCS from GCS as someone had suggested on a forum. Again, nothing. As for dissolve all, once it went through and nothing showed up. The other time, it just hung. Am I missing something perhaps in my installation?

Comment: What is the CRS of your data and what is the CRS of your project?

Comment: could you provide your shapefile?

Comment: Sorry, been stuck with other work. The CRS was initially in WGS84. I have tried it in that as well as changed to PCS (UTM zone 43N). Both seem to fail in my version of QGIS. Will share the shapefile soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run V.clean toolbox (snap, break) before running "dissolve". It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Convert the shapefile to .kml layer first then use dissolve. After dissolve, you can then convert the kml layer back to shp. Worked for me.